# Flot: How to keep x and y axes the same scale?

Tags: flot

I want to plot on a standard Cartesian plane, so 1 unit on x axis has the same length as 1 unit on y axis. I also use the navigate plugin to zoom and pan. Is there anyway I can have this constraint? can't find anything about this in Flot api.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar and this was the first test: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBcPb/)

The main point is that you set the max values for the axis in the same ratio as the width and height of your placeholder div:

```
options.xaxes[0].max = options.yaxes[0].max * $('#ph').width() / $('#ph').height();
$.plot($('#ph'), data, options);
```

Comment: in your fiddle ,you have to include jquery.flot.navigate.js unless it won't work.here is edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mBcPb/1/

Comment: @ThusithaSumanadasa my fiddle works for the aspect ratio, but did not include zooming and panning.

Comment: @Raidri- I mentioned it because ,you adds zooming and panning to your fiddle.If you don't include  jquery.flot.navigate.js to your fiddle,adding zoom and pan properties are useless