# jQuery Flot - Force same tick interval on X and Y when zooming in/ out

Tags: plot, flot, scatter-plot

I have a grid in jQuery Flot. On this grid, there are a lot of separate points scattered across, each with an X and a Y position.

[image]

Additionally, the grid utilizes flot.navigation to allow zooming in and out. Now this is where my problem occurs... This is undoubtedly rectangles, where as the first image, and most zoom levels, are square..

[image]

To force squares on the initial load, I normalize the data x/y values. When I zoom in/ out, the grid is still square, for a while. If I zoom in and out sporadically, the grid becomes rectangles.

Removing the scroll-zoom, and adding zoom in/ zoom out buttons did not fix the issue. While testing this, I realized that if I pan up a little bit, so that 0,0 is not visible, that's when the zoom and ratio starts to act up.

Applying the fix suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128828/1047409) didn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flot: How to keep x and y axes the same scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951796/flot-how-to-keep-x-and-y-axes-the-same-scale)

Comment: Unfortunately, applying the change suggested in the other answer does now solve my issue.